# Computing producer and user accuracy for each class in Google Earth Engine supervised classification

Tags: google-earth-engine, image-classification

I know I can get a confusion matrix and an overall accuracy, but is there a way to calculate producer and user accuracy for each class separately from the Google Earth Engine?

This is my validation dataset: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/RohitNandakumar/accuracy

This is my training dataset: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/RohitNandakumar/train

```
var sent = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR"),
    table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/RohitNandakumar/train"),
    geometry = 
    /* color: #d63000 */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[79.34242573948666, 29.562958506122595],
          [79.34242573948666, 29.296831501244323],
          [79.79217854710384, 29.296831501244323],
          [79.79217854710384, 29.562958506122595]]], null, false),
    accuracy = ee.FeatureCollection("users/RohitNandakumar/accuracy");
var land = sent.filterDate('2019-04-1','2019-11-01')
.filterMetadata("MGRS_TILE","equals",'44RLT')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE",5))
.sort('system:time_start');
var image = ee.Image(land.toList(land.size()).get(1)).clip(geometry)//.aside(print);

//supervised classification
var label = 'MC_ID';
var bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B9','B11','B12']
var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: table,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 10
});
var training = training.randomColumn().filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', 0.1))
var trained = ee.Classifier.cart().train(training, label, bands);
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(trained);

var validation = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: accuracy,
  properties: [label],
});
var validated = validation.classify(trained);
var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('MC_ID', 'classification');
print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should run the functions `reduceRegion()` and/or `reproject()` before the supervised classification, because this bands are not in the same scale.

To answer your question: try to interpret the confusion matrix, there you can evaluate if a pixel was classified in the wrong class.